# How do I format text inside a span tag in HTML on Wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress, html

I dont want to change the font of the text using a pre or code tag. I would like to get it formatted correctly using the current font and strong tag setting. here is my html code

`<strong><span style="color: #3366ff;">C++:</span></strong>
<strong><span style="color: #3366ff;">     Size_(_Tp _width, _Tp _height);
     typedef Size_ Size2i;
     typedef Size2i Size;</span></strong>`

And he output is this, as is:

`C++:
Size_(_Tp _width, _Tp _height);
typedef Size_ Size2i;
typedef Size2i Size;`

I would like the output to be this:

`C++: Size_(_Tp _width, _Tp _height);
     typedef Size_<int> Size2i;
     typedef Size2i Size;`

How do I change my html code to get my desired result. I've tried changing the position of the text in the span tag, and changing which tags are on the outside, none have provided the desired result. This is a free wordpress.com blog. Thanks in advance for any help:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<strong style="color: #3366ff;">
    C++: Size_(_Tp _width, _Tp _height);<br>
    <span style="margin-left: 30px;">typedef Size_ Size2i;</span><br>
    <span style="margin-left: 30px;">typedef Size2i Size;</span>
</strong>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/bWE9C/